# French language : is it possible to use a possessive adjective earlier than the name it refers to?

Tags: french, word-order, spoken-language

I have posted [the same question on the French language Stackexchange](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/51058/un-adjectif-possessif-peut-il-renvoyer-%c3%a0-un-nom-prononc%c3%a9-post%c3%a9rieurement-dans-la), and I have been referred to post it here too.

---

A phrase said by Mireille left me dumbfounded:

> **Bénédicte** et *ses* filles ont souhaité un bon anniversaire à leur mère.

The reason I got confused was because I knew, as well as Mireille, that Bénédicte had no daughters, but only sisters. I corructed her sentence this way, by the more logical sentence:

> **Bénédicte** et *ses* sœurs  ont souhaité un bon anniversaire à leur mère.

Mireille doubled down and blamed me for misinterprenting her sentence, and argued I should have unterstood it this way:

> Bénédicte et *ses* filles ont souhaité un bon anniversaire à **leur mère**.

And this was a perfectly valid way to order such a sentence.

I have two questions :

- Is this way with words allowed in French ?
- If that's the case, what is the name of the figure of speech?

__

Comment: So you're asking whether French allow cataphora in the same way that English does? I'd be very surprised if it doesn't, (Though this example would be subject to misconstruction in English just as in French).

Comment: Do you find the sentence troublesome if you remove Bénédicte from it? « Ses filles lui ont souhaité un bon anniversaire » sounds reasonable enough to me (though I’m not a native speaker). As Colin says, the example wouldn’t work in English either: “Her daughters wished her a happy birthday” is acceptable, but “Benedicte and her daughters wished her a happy birthday” needs a good deal of syntactically contortionist manoeuvres to be parsed with the two instances of _her_ being coreferential.

Comment: I don't think they should have referred you here - this looks like a grammar usage question that belongs on the French language site.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet If you remove Bénédicte, « Ses filles ont souhaité un bon anniversaire à leur mère »  = Her daughters wished *their* mother a happy birthday. So it's not two *hers*. Could parse that "her daughters* is not bound to Bénédicte?

Comment: Your questions do not contain "a possessive adjective before the name it refers to". This is not a linguistics question, anyway. It's seems to be a family relationship problem. So I dunno why it turned  up here.

Comment: @Lambie it does. I may have mistranslated the grammatical class of "ses"

Comment: I don't see where you translated it in your question. But anyway, this is grammar not linguistics, really.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about the grammar of a particular language are not generally on-topic here, and the French site should not have redirected you here

Comment: The question also asks for the name of the “figure of speech”, which is of course on topic.